# Manipulating TFS 2017 webform in the URL

Tags: url, tfs

I am trying to create a direct link to a TFS work item.  I know Microsoft publishes how to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/work-item-url-hyperlink), but I want to highlight a section by maximizing it.  I can click on the Maximize button for a control group manually, but is there a way to perform this function automatically using the parameters in the '_workitem?' API?

Something to the effect of:

```
http://{server}/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_workitem?id={ID}&_a=edit&maximizegroup={controlGroupName}
```

Bonus points for providing documentation on all options for the _workitem? API.

Please let me know if anything in my question needs clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my test, we can only define the hyperlink to maximize the work item itself, cannot maximize the specific section within the work item.

Also tried with the [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool, but no API tracked to maximize the specific section.

To maximize the work item:

```
http://server:8080/tfs/{Collection}/{Project}/_workitems?id={ID}&_a=edit&fullScreen=true
```